# Selecting specified subtype from List in C#

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion, type-inference

I have a function that, when given a `List<T>`, selects from it a `List<V>` such that `V : T`:

Current implemetation is:

```
public List<V> Subset<T, V>(IEnumerable<T> exo)
    where V : class
    where V : T
{
    return exo.Where(elem => elem is V).Select(elem => elem as V).ToList();
}
```

Although I feel something more concise should work because it is stated that `V` is a subclass of `T`:

```
// Does not comile: can not implicitly convert List<T> to List<V>
public List<V> Subset<T, V>(IEnumerable<T> exo) where V : T
{
    return exo.Where(elem => elem is V).ToList();
}
```

Can you please explain why it fails to infer correct type and perhaps if my current implemetation is the best possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) which filters sequence based on parameter type:

```
return exo.OfType<V>().ToList();
```

Why your second code not works - it selects items which is V from sequence, but result type is still list of `T`. Sequence just filtered by some predicate (it does not matter what you checked there - is item of type V, or maybe is item not null, or some other condition). You know what you checked, but compiler still treats result as a sequence of filtered base class objects.

And you can't return list of base class objects from method, which should return list of derived objects. If it would be possible, then you could return not filtered list of base classes.

Comment: Nice one. Why does this approach work while `exo.Where(elem => elem is V).ToList()` does not?